# Show multiple colums with MAX in sql

Tags: sql, max

I am trying to write a query that shows the names of people with the highest salary in one of my tables.

Currently I have

```
SELECT MAX (salaris) 
FROM (Technischdirecteur);
```

But this only shows a number and not the corresponding name to it. How would I go about adding the name of the person that has this salary?

Comment: Show the table structure.

Comment: Why was this dinged? There is no reason for that. There is nothing more required to answer his question.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple You can go with this way

And also you can choose the column you want to display by replacing the `*`

```
select * 
From Technischdirecteur
Where salaris= (Select Max(salaris) From Technischdirecteur)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, c.name 
  FROM Technischdirecteur a, club c
       (SELECT MAX(salaris) salaris FROM Technischdirecteur) b 
 WHERE a.salaris = b.salaris 
   AND a.cl_id = c.cl_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I also have a table called Club. The primary key is cl_id, and it has an attribute called name. In the table from TechnischDirecteur I have a FK to cl_id, how could I show the club name in the result you posted above?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values, don't think `MAX()`, think `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT td.* 
FROM Technischdirecteur td
ORDER BY salary desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Depending on the database, the `LIMIT 1` could be `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`, `TOP 1` (in the `SELECT` clause`, or even something else.